# How to write multiple lines into a text file using golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to write errors into a text file. However, I can't seem to figure out why it's not printing multiple errors. It just prints the latest one.

```
        for {
            if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
                ...   
                break
            } else {
                data := fmt.Sprintf("[" + time.Now().Format("15:04:05") +"] " + strconv.Itoa(resp.StatusCode) + string(body) + "\n")
                file, err := os.Open("assets/errors.txt")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }

                write := bufio.NewWriter(file)
                write.WriteString(data)
                write.Flush()
            }
```

Comment: The code shown contains only a single write, not multiple ones. It also opens the file in read-only mode, so writing should not work even once. Please update your question with code which actually makes it possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: He is using an infinity loop `for { ... }`.

Comment: `os.Open` opens a file for reading, not writing.  https://pkg.go.dev/os#Open And if it fails, it's returned filehandle won't be valid.  Don't ignore errors from any functions, including `WriteString` - you're just setting yourself up for unexpected behavior by ignoring errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest you creating a function for that, as simple like:

```golang
func LogErrors(errors []error, filePath string) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(f)

    for _, e := range errors {
        writer.WriteString(e.Error())
        writer.WriteString("\n")
    }

    writer.Flush()
    return nil
}
```

And you can use it like:

```golang
func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    filePath := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/log-%s", t.Format("2006-01-02_15_04_05"))

    es := []error{
        errors.New("something is bad"),
        errors.New("another error fix it"),
    }
    LogErrors(es, filePath)
}
```

Comment: I don't think `os.Create` is quite right either, since that will truncate existing files.  I would expect this file to be opened with `os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRITEONLY` (https://pkg.go.dev/os#O_APPEND)

Comment: yeah, you are right, let me modify it.